# Can I pass parameters from a dashboard/viewsheet to another dashboard in InetSoft's Style Intelligence?

Tags: business-intelligence

Is it possible to pass parameters from one dashboard/viewsheet to another dashboard via a hyperlink/drilldown, in InetSoft's Style Intelligence?  If so, how so?

It appears that parameters can be passed from a report (see steps 10 and 11 here, particularly the picture under step 11: http://community.inetsoft.com/docs/11.3/devhelp/rd1352720.htm) to another report or dashboard/viewsheet, but I'm trying to pass parameters from a viewsheet, not a report.

I tried adding a hyperlink to a textbox, but nothing populates in the *Value* pane, even though I have some *selection* and *input* UI elements on the viewsheet, and variables defined on the associated worksheet:

[image]

Does that mean the feature is not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the *Value* pane is only populated when a hyperlink is associated with a table cell.

I ended up using a script to modify the *hyperlink* property of the textbox to pass the parameters to the second viewsheet.  Right-click the textbox, select Properties..., Script tab, Script radio button:

```
d0 = new Date(RangeSlider1.selectedObjects[0])
d1 = new Date(RangeSlider1.selectedObjects[1])
d0_str = formatDate(d0, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
d1_str = formatDate(d1, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
dashboard2Link.hyperlink="http://server_name/sree/Reports?op=vs&path=/playground%20-%20db2&VSPARAM_start_time=" + d0_str + "&VSPARAM_end_time=" + d1_str
//alert(reportLink.hyperlink);  // debug
```

I also changed the textbox hyperlink option to "None".